# Simple gate figure

Tags: floats, diagrams

What is the simplest way to create gates like the one in the picture? Is there a specific package that people most often use?

[image: simple gate]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the package [qcircuit](https://ctan.org/pkg/qcircuit) should do the trick.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{qcircuit}
\begin{document}
  \Qcircuit @C=1em @R=.3em {
    & \lstick{i} & \gate{O_f} & \rstick{f(i)} \qw
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version using [`tikz`](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 3pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, minimum size = 2em] (O) {$O_f$};
  \node[coordinate] (f) [right of = O, node distance = 1.5cm]{};
  \node[coordinate] (i) [left of = O, node distance = 1.5cm]{};
  \draw[] (O) -- (f) node[right]{$f(i)$};
  \draw[] (i) node[left]{$i$} -- (O);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```